# Excessive whitespace in text output from XSLT 2.0 transfom

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm testing code I need for a project, however the output has unexpected whitespace that would be problematic. The placement of the `<xsl:text>` element ***should*** only result in a newline, but I may be wrong. My biggest fear is that ***I'm*** generating the extra whitespace due to my lack of experience so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  The stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="files">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="file"  group-by="@project">
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
            <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The test source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<files>
  <file name="swablr.eps"     size="4313" project="mars"/>
  <file name="batboy.wks"     size="424"  project="neptune"/>
  <file name="potrzebie.dbf"  size="1102" project="jupiter"/>
  <file name="kwatz.xom"      size="43"   project="jupiter"/>
  <file name="paisley.doc"    size="988"  project="neptune"/>
  <file name="ummagumma.zip"  size="2441" project="mars"/>
  <file name="schtroumpf.txt" size="389"  project="mars"/>
  <file name="mondegreen.doc" size="1993" project="neptune"/>
  <file name="gadabout.pas"   size="685"  project="jupiter"/>
</files>
```

Actual output:

```
mars
                    neptune
                    jupiter
```

Desired result:

```
mars
neptune
jupiter
```

I'm transforming the source using Saxon-HE s9api via node-java. So far I've tried `xsl:strip-space` as well as `normalize-space(current-grouping-key())` both of which fail. Thanks in advance.

J.

Comment: Yeah you’re generating the white space. Try using `<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>` instead. (Or add the xA reference to the xsl:value-of with a concat.)

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks!!! Could you explain how I cacked this up? Like how I generated the whitespace so I don't do it again.

Comment: The white space comes from your xsl:text. All of the white space inside of it is included in the output. So since the end tag is indented, all that space is included.

Comment: Basically, it has taken all the content between the text tag and input that into the output. What do you have there? A new line and several spaces.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up to the second comment written by *DanielHaley*
(*The white space comes from...*):

It takes some experience in XSLT and perceptivity, to spot
what was wrong in your script and apparently *DanielHaley* wrote
the proper solution after his first glance at your question.

You are probably accustomed to stepwise indenting of embedded XSLT code,
e.g. within your `for-each-group` loop there are 3 equally indented
lines:

- `xsl:value-of`,
- `xsl:text` - opening tag,
- `/xsl:text` - closing tag.

To some extent, this is good. It looks neat, but sometimes it is also needed
to figure out, what you have actually said with such code.

After `<xsl:text>` you have actually:

- a newline,
- a number of spaces (or tabs),
- and finally `</xsl:text>`, closing the text to be output.

So, there is a difference between what you **intended** to be output
and what your (neatly looking) script outputs **actually**.
You wanted to output only a newline, whereas your code actually
outputs some extra spaces, spoiling the result.

Now, at least, you gained some experience, how to write XSLT code
and how to avoid mistakes of this type.

Comment: Thanks for adding a proper answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, it is often overlooked that you can also use `xsl:value-of separator="..."` to directly separate the items of a wrapped sequence as needed so your code can be rewritten as

```
<xsl:template match="files">
    <xsl:value-of separator="&#10;">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="file"  group-by="@project">
        <xsl:sequence select="current-grouping-key()"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:value-of>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Cp

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:template match="files">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="file"  group-by="@project">
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <xsl:text>&#x0a;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:template>
check it
```

Comment: Don’t just add code as an answer. Please provide explanation to make it complete.